# How to show this sequence diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The problem is that:

Let $x_{1}=1$
  and define inductively $x_{n+1}=(x_{1}+\cdots+x_{n})/2$
 . Prove that $x_{n}\rightarrow\infty$
 .

I tried to solve it. But it is nonsense that $x_{n+1}$=$(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)/2=(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n-1})/2+x_n/2=x_n/2+x_n/2=x_n$. How can I handle it?

Comment: You have divided by $2$ once too often. Look again at your chain of equations you declared nonsense, compare with the definition, and spot the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have:
$x_{n+1}=(x_1+x_2+\cdots + x_n)/2 = (x_1+x_2+\cdots + x_{n-1})/2 + x_n/2 = x_n +x_n/2 = 3x_n/2$ which holds for $n>2$.

Simply testing the first few terms of the sequence : $1$, $1/2$, $3/4$ $\cdots$ should tell you that this is not a constant sequence so there is something amiss with your algebra.

Comment: The first terms are $1,\frac12,\frac34$, if I calculated correctly.

Comment: Your start of the sequence is wrong, $x_2 = (x_1)/2 = 1/2,\, x_3 = (x_1 + x_2)/2 = (1 + 1/2)/2 = 3/4,\dotsc$. The relation $x_{n+1} = \frac{3}{2}x_n$ holds only for $n \geqslant 2$.